# Included homomorphism $\phi_P: R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}\to S_P$ is local homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Given a ring homomorphism $\phi\colon R\to S$, the universal property of $R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}$
includes $\phi_P: R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}\to S_P$. More explicity $\phi_P(a/s)=\phi(a)/\phi(s)$.

(the details here is little foggy to me, on how exactly $\phi_P$ get included by the universal property ? Αnd how we end up with $\phi_P(a/s)=\phi(a)/\phi(s)$? ).

If $\phi_P(a/s)=\phi(a)/\phi(s)$, then we can show that it's a local homomorphism. Let $\mathrm{m,n}$ be the maximal ideals of $R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}, S_P$ respectfully.

Since $a/s \in m$ then  $a\in \phi^{-1}(P) \Rightarrow \phi(a)\in P$

Also, it's true that
if $s\notin \phi^{-1}(P)$ It's that $\phi(s)\notin P$.

Thus, $\phi(a)/\phi(s)\in \mathrm{n}$.

I can't see why is this: "$s\notin \phi^{-1}(P)$ It's that $\phi(s)\notin P$" true.
Does it accrue on how we define $\phi_P$ by the universal property ?

Does the universal property tell us that it indeed it exist such homomorphism $\phi_P$, and then we give the type $\phi_P(a/s)=\phi(a)/\phi(s) $ ?

Comment: By definition, $\phi^{-1}(P)$ is the set of elements $r \in R$ such that $\phi(r) \in P$. Therefore $s \not \in \phi^{-1}(P)$ just means $\phi(s) \not \in P$.

Comment: @Don Thanks, I missed that even thought it was trivial. Do you know, maybe how we get $\phi_P(a/s)=\phi(a)/\phi(s) ?$

Comment: I've written an explanation as an answer below. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain how the universal property induces a homomorphism $\phi_P: R_{\phi^{-1}(P)} \to S_P$.

We first recall the universal property of localisations:

> **Proposition.** Let $A$ and $B$ two commutative rings, $S \subseteq A$ a multiplicative system and $\phi: A \to B$ a ring homomorphism. Denote by $\iota: A \to AS^{-1}$ the canonical map. If $\phi(S) \subseteq B^\times$, then there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\overline{\phi}: AS^{-1} \to B$ such that $\phi = \overline{\phi} \circ \iota$. In that case, $\overline{\phi}$ is given by $\overline{\phi}(a/s)=\phi(a)\phi(s)^{-1}$.

We know apply this result to our case. Let $\alpha: R \to R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}$ and $\beta: S \to S_P$ be the canonical maps. Consider the ring homomorphism $\beta \circ \phi: R \to S_P$. Recall that
$$S_P^\times = \left\{\frac{s}{y} \ \middle| \ s,y \in S-P\right\}.$$
If $x \in R-\phi^{-1}(P)$, then $\phi(x) \in S-P$ and
$$\beta \circ \phi (x)=\frac{\phi(x)}{1} \in S_P^\times.$$
By the universal property of localisation stated above, there exists a unique ring homomorphism $\phi_P: R_{\phi^{-1}(P)} \to S_P$ such that
$$\beta \circ \phi = \phi_P \circ \alpha.$$
As it is mentioned in the proposition, $\phi_P: R_{\phi^{-1}(P)} \to S_P$ is given by
$$\phi_P\left(\frac{r}{x}\right)=\left(\frac{\phi(r)}{1}\right)\left(\frac{\phi(x)}{1}\right)^{-1}=\frac{\phi(r)}{\phi(x)}.$$

Comment: Do you knkw where can I find the  proof of the proposition ?

Comment: @lupusnox You should find it in any basic commutative algebra book. For instance, see Proposition 3.1 in Atiyah and MacDonald's *Introduction to Commutative Algebra*.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might found something If $\alpha:R\to R_{\phi^{-1}(P)}$ and $\beta:S\to S_P$ are the localization homomorphisms, then the map $\phi_P$ is the unique homomorphism such that $\phi_P\circ\alpha=\beta\circ\varphi$.

If we do some calculations, we end up with $\phi_P(a/s)\phi_P(s)=\phi(a)/1$

And we get the expected homomorphism only if  $\phi_P(s)=\phi(s)$ as $\phi(s)$ is invertible.

So why is it true that $\phi_P(s)=\phi(s)$?